# asp.net uploading big files: throws System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, out-of-memory

I'd like to upload big files via ASP.NET to WCF service. Until 100 MB is not a problem, my configuration works perfectly, but above 100 MB it throws System.OutOfMemoryException.

The uploading method works with FileStream, but before that, I save the file to a temporary folder. Not sure if this is the problem, or something else. I add the code of my controller, which takes care of calling the wcf service.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images"), fileName);

                file.SaveAs(path);

                FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

                TileService.TileServiceClient client = new TileService.TileServiceClient();
                client.Open();
                client.UploadFile(fileName, fsSource);
                client.Close();

                fsSource.Dispose();
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                }
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("");
    }
```

The method is called like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<input type="file" name="FileUploader" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload file" />
}
```

In the ASP.NET web.config I already set the following things: *executionTimeout, maxRequestLength, requestLengthDiskThreshold, maxAllowedContentLength*. I add the binding part of the configuration.

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITileService"
      closeTimeout="24:01:00" openTimeout="24:01:00" receiveTimeout="24:10:00" sendTimeout="24:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="4294967295" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="4294967295" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: You can try reading it in chunks using the Request.Files[0].InputStream

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not in the code I think. The ASP.NET project was hosted in IIS Express instead of Local IIS. Since I changed that in project properties everything works smoothly.

I'm using now @nimeshjm 's code though. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try reading it in chunks using the Request.Files[0].InputStream

Something along these lines:

```
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images"), fileName);

                using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int count;
                    while ((count = file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
                    {
                        fs.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                }

                FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

                TileService.TileServiceClient client = new TileService.TileServiceClient();
                client.Open();
                client.UploadFile(fileName, fsSource);
                client.Close();

                fsSource.Dispose();
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                }
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("");
    }
```

Comment: Might be a good idea, but it writes:
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.

Any ideas? :-/

Comment: while ((count += file.InputStream.Read(buffer, count, 1024)) > 0)

not sure if byte[1024] is enough? I should be able to upload up to 2 GB files. I tested with 270 MB file.

Comment: A slight bug in the original sample :)
I've updated the example, give that a go.

Comment: Now your code is working for small files (tested for 33 MB), but I still get System.OutOfMemoryException for big files (tested for 270 MB) :(

Comment: Which line throws that exception?

Comment: I figured it out... The problem was with the project properties, not the code (I think). Thanks for your help though, I will use your code.