# .xml big file Uploading error - System.OutOfMemoryException in asp.net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am uploading .xml file but getting error '**System.OutOfMemoryException**' on **ds.GetXml();**  in asp.net with C#.

**small .xml file is working fine** but big file not. **i am trying with 60 mb file** but it failed and getting memory exception on **ds.GetXml()** method.

Detail view :
System.OutOfMemoryException: The function evaluation was disabled because of an out of memory exception.

```
DataSet dsCompendium = General.getDataSet4mXML(strFilePath,strFileName); 
// this is custom function to get dataset from XML : getDataSet4mXML(string,string)
DataTable dtCompendium = dsCompendium.Tables[1];
strXML = dsCompendium.GetXml();

<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" maxRequestLength="1048576" />     

<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

help me out

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: inserted code..getting error over here..

Answer (score 0):

See the values for maxRequestLength value of httpRunTime in web.config. Try changing it to a bigger number.

Comment: maxRequestLength="314572800"

Comment: I go with this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921019/asp-net-uploading-big-files-throws-system-outofmemoryexception and work perfectly.. i change project properties iis express to local iis than work perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like **HTTP web request** size is exceeding in your case.

The 4MB default is set in machine.config, but you can override it in you web.config. For instance, to expand the upload limit to 20MB, you'd do this:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>
```

**Edit**

For IIS7 and above, you also need to add the lines below:

```
 <system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

Note: maxAllowedContentLength is measured in bytes

Comment: <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" maxRequestLength="314572800" />

Comment: Have you checked request limit at IIS end?

Comment: [This](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits) link will help you out to check same.

Comment: This configuration not work on iis express on vs2013 project properties. when i change project properties => web => server => IIS Express to Local IIS it work perfectly but not working on iis express. But Question is why not on iis express on i.e. localhost: 1202 this still not solved. any idea about this @geekyninja.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DataSet ReadXml(XmlReader) method.

To create XmlReader

```
FileStream st = File.Open(@"filepath", FileMode.Open);
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(st);  
DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
ds.ReadXml(reader);
```